# How to submit forms via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

My form function is written in PHP and is expecting two variables to be passed. I have to submit the form and the variables using Javascript though. I understand I can use `.submit()` to actually submit the form using JavaScript but the variables that need to be passed to my form function are stored in two variables within my JavaScript. I'm having trouble understanding how to pass those JavaScript variables when I submit the form using `.submit()`.

One idea that I have is adding hidden fields to my html form and setting the value of those hidden input values to what I have in my JavaScript variables.

I'm wondering if there is a way to to use `.submit()` and pass the variables via JavaScript?

Comment: If you don't need to use ajax, just put your variables in an hidden input inside the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) for a plain vanilla JS solution without jQuery:

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("username", "Groucho");
formData.append("accountnum", 123456); 

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://foo.com/submitform.php");
request.send(formData);
```

There are [examples](http://www.sagarganatra.com/2011/07/submitting-form-using-formdata-object.html) how to use it with an existing form:

JS:

```
var docFormElement = document.getElementById('myForm');  
var docFormData = new FormData(docFormElement);  
docFormData.append("product_license","Enterprise");
var xhrObject = new XMLHttpRequest();  
xhrObject.open("POST","postform.cfm");  
xhrObject.send(docFormData);
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">  
   <input name="product_name" type="text" value="ColdFusion" />  
   <input name="product_codename" type="text" value="Zeus" />  
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either keep a hidden input or a javascript variable to keep track of values. You can then use AJAX to submit values to PHP page :

```
<input id="name" type="hidden" .....
....


var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone;
  //alert (dataString);return false;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "yourpage.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
      //do something
    }
  });
```

details:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery--net-59

Alternatively you can just update the hidden input values and submit the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
    document.forms["formID"].submit();
}
</script>
<form id="formID" action="somepage.php">
Search: <input type='hidden' name='email'>
<a href="javascript: submitform()">Submit</a>
</form>
```